# Show that the expression $\frac{px^2+3x-4}{p+3x-4x^2}$ will be capable of all values when $x$ is real, provided that p has any value between 1 and 7 .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> Show that the expression $\frac{px^2+3x-4}{p+3x-4x^2}$ will be capable of all values when $x$ is real, provided that $p$ has any value between 1 and 7 .

**What I've tried :**

Let $\frac{px^2+3x-4}{p+3x-4x^2} = y$. Then,
$px^2 + 3x - 4 = py + 3xy - 4x^2y$
or, $(p+4y)x^2 + 3(1-y)x -4-py = 0$
Since, $x \in R$, $D ≥ 0$ implying, $9(1-y)^2-4(p+4y)(-4-py) ≥ 0$
or, $(9+16p)y^2+(46+4p^2)y+9+16p ≥ 0$
which further implies $9+16p ≥ 0$ .

I'm stuck here can't think further and there are solutions on the net but none of them explains well after this step ..

Answer (score 3):

> $$(9+16p)y^2+(46+4p^2)y+9+16p\ge0$$Which further implies $9+16p\ge0$.

That's not right. Notice that all three summands there could possibly be negative, for example (say) $1+3-2\ge0$ is a possibility or maybe $-5+3+3\ge0$ or ... I made those numbers up and when I say "possibility" I mean in the general sense, if you have $a+b+c\ge0$ it can be the case that any of $a,b,c$ are negative.

Also note that you want that quantity to be nonnegative for *all* $y$. So you're basically asking:

> For which values of $p$ is the quadratic: $$y\mapsto(9+16p)y^2+(46+4p^2)y+(9+16p)$$Nonnegative?

And there's a standard way to answer that question, which is by showing the discriminant of the quadratic is nonnegative and the leading coefficient is positive. So try doing that!

Comment: Yeah in every kind of solution this is shown . But how non negativity of discriminant shows the quadratic is positive ?

Comment: @Ash_Blanc There are three situations for a real quadratic. Case (1): It has no roots, and the discriminant is positive. Then, it is either always negative or always positive (according to the sign of the leading coefficient). Case (2): It has a repeated root, and the discriminant is zero. Then it is either always nonnegative or always nonpositive according to the sign of the leading coefficient. Case (3): the discriminant is negative, in which case the quadratic will assume both positive and negative values

Comment: Well @FShrike if u don't mind can u elaborate the first case .

Comment: @Ash_Blanc We can make this formal but let’s make it make sense first. Draw a graph! No roots means the quadratic never cuts the $x$-axis and so it either just curves down-then-up (“smiley face quadratic”) in the positive half plane or curves up-then-down (“sad face quadratic”) in the negative half plane. It should be clear that if the square coefficient is positive, the sign must be positive (at least for all large values and thus for all values) and similarly if the square coefficient is negative